# DOM Click event never registers if an entity is updating fast

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

This can be clicked: https://jsfiddle.net/tgrL3vnh/1/

```
<div id='gg'>One second</div>
<style></style>
<script>
    var click_num=1;
    setInterval(function(){
        var html="<div onclick='alert(click_num++)'>I can be clicked!</div>";
        // $('#gg').html(html);
        document.getElementById('gg').innerHTML=html;
    },2000);
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log(click_num);
    }, false);
</script>
```

This can't be clicked: https://jsfiddle.net/tgrL3vnh/2/

```
<div id='gg'>One second</div>
<style></style>
<script>
    var click_num=1;
    setInterval(function(){
        var html="<div onclick='alert(click_num++)'>I can't be clicked!</div>";
        // $('#gg').html(html);
        document.getElementById('gg').innerHTML=html;
    },20);
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log(click_num);
    }, false);
</script>
```

I have an html including game with interfaces updating occasionally, approximately 5% of the time, clicks to these interfaces are lost, it's very annoying, I'm wondering how I can work around this

In the above example, you can observe this scenario in it's most extreme form, if an entity is updating every 20ms, you can never click it, even at 2000ms, sometimes the clicks don't register, but if you look at the console logs, the clicks can register anywhere else in the page

TL;DR: Only when you click an updating DOM entity, the click event can never be observed, I want to observe it and work around the issue

Comment: One solution is to put an overlay on top of an updating entity, catch the click, manually register it by traversing `document.elementsFromPoint` - however, this overlay prevents pointer events, so clickable things no longer change to the hand pointer

Comment: Hi there. I dont know if this helps, but take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60237348/dom-click-event-never-registers-if-an-entity-is-updating-fast

Answer (score 0):

One solution came from our community, `onmousedown` instead of `onclick` works in this scenario

This was the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w93hLkpe/1/

In hindsight, it does make sense, the entity gets removed before mouse up, click doesn't complete, I'm just surprised there wasn't any information online about this problem/solution - I ended up integrating this fix, along with localised updates wherever possible, together they make the ux smooth as expected